# Erase previously drawn window in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

am trying to move a custom button whose base class is CWnd, am using MoveWindow() method but each time i move the window the previously drawn window is still visible. i tryed to call InvalidateWindow, InvalidateRect together with UpdateWindow on the parent window but all didn't work. i also tried RedrawWindow nothing happend. how can i properly update the parent window with the new position of the button?
here is my sample code

```
void CCalendarCtrl::Shift()
{
   RECT rc;
   m_Up.GetWindowRect(&rc);
   rc.top -= 20;
   rc.bottom -=20;
   m_Up.MoveWindow(&rc,TRUE);
   RedrawWindow();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call [Invalidate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx) after movewindow().

Answer (score 1):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6da8041-747c-4b31-b493-343e4516b452/are-the-coordinates-returned-by-cwndgetwindowrect-mfc-and-cwndmovewindow-mfc?forum=vcmfcatl

GetWindowRect returns screen coordinates. MoveWindow works using Client coordinates. So you need to do ScreenToClient(&rc) between the two calls.